# Searching for data from file1 in file2

Tags: text-processing, python3

I have two csv files with the same structure.

file1.csv:

```
352075|6505286781|6505286781|165|A|2.6.37-3.2|25353gb1FAa8
172238|8136090512|8136090512|1|A|2.6.37-3.2|255411429E02
105767|1783707658|1783707658|82|A|2.6.37-3.2|375g1043DC92
352092|2214612065|2214612065|22|A|2.6.37-3.2|07k9975cad1e
```

file2.csv:

```
274451|24575|24575|3872531727|23|24575|2017-11-08 11:43:21.15|2017-11-25 16:30:21.061|STB|375g1043DC92|375g1043DC92
506406|280335|280335|4516157218|22|280335|2017-11-22 15:44:54.307|2017-11-29 11:26:02.123|STB|256d9739d3cc|256d9739d3cc
367536|163226|163226|5007632889|9|163226|2017-11-15 20:37:02.034|2017-11-28 20:55:24.891|STB|25353gb1FAa8|25353gb1FAa8
374253|254874|254874|9263432532|23|254874|2017-11-16 19:17:52.827|2017-11-28 19:25:23.805|STB|37fe9739b5a0|37fe9739b5a0
```

I need to check data from file1 in the file2 (data from file1 from column [6]).

I would like to use Python to do this. I tried:

```py
import csv
with open('file1.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
  list1 = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
  for row in list1:
    print(row[6])
```

But how I can check these data one by one in `file2.csv` and if data present - print it, if absent provide another operation?

Comment: Mind that the first element in a list has index 0. Please clarify what collumn exactly should have a match in what column in both files, and what exactly should be the action if True or False.

Comment: I need to check a match in row[6] (index 6) from file1.csv (list1) and row1[9] (index 9) from file2.csv (maybe I need to import file2.csv to the list2....).
if row[6] == row1[9]:
  print("True")
else:
  print("False")

Comment: I don't think we should close this question. The only reason for closing seems to be that it asks for help with a Python approach, but general text-processing questions are on-topic here (and often receive Python-based answers) and answers using other tools could be used to achieve the desired result could be posted here (questions are not only for their askers).

Answer (score 1):

You would not even need to use `csv.reader()` for doing this. Here is an example (working in python 3.6) how to do it without, just using the python built-in functions and the `sys` library for parsing the command line. So here's example one without the `csv` library, lets call it `search_basic.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6

from sys import argv


def parse_files(name_1, name_2):
    """Opens two files and checks if pos #6 in each row of file 1 is present in file2 via simple build-ins"""
    try:
        with open(file=name_1) as file_1, open(file=name_2) as file_2:
                data_1 = file_1.readlines()
                data_2 = file_2.readlines()
                mapping = {
                    row.strip('\n').split('|')[-1]: row.strip('\n').split('|')
                    for row in data_2
                }
                for row in data_1:
                    last_column = row.strip('\n').split('|')[-1]
                    if last_column in mapping:
                        print(f'{last_column} found in {mapping[last_column]}')
                    else:
                        print(f'{last_column} not found, doing other operation')
    except FileNotFoundError as error:
        print('{}'.format(error))
        exit(1)
    else:
        return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(argv) <= 1:
        print('No parameters given...')
        exit(1)
    elif len(argv) == 2:
        print('Only one file was given...')
        exit(1)
    else:
        parse_files(argv[1], argv[2])
        exit(0)
```

But if you insist on using the `csv` library here's example (working in python 3.6) two doing it with `csv.reader()`, let's call it `search_csv.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6

import csv
from sys import argv


def parse_files(name_1, name_2):
    """Opens two files and checks if pos #6 in each row of file 1 is present in file2 via simple build-ins"""
    try:
        with open(file=name_1) as file_1, open(file=name_2) as file_2:
            mapping = {
                row[-1]: row
                for row in csv.reader(file_2, delimiter='|')
            }

            for row in csv.reader(file_1, delimiter='|'):
                last_column = row[-1]
                if last_column in mapping:
                    print(f'{last_column} found in {mapping[last_column]}')
                else:
                    print(f'{last_column} not found, doing other operation')
    except FileNotFoundError as error:
        print('{}'.format(error))
        exit(1)
    else:
        return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(argv) <= 1:
        print('No parameters given...')
        exit(1)
    elif len(argv) == 2:
        print('Only one file was given...')
        exit(1)
    else:
        parse_files(argv[1], argv[2])
        exit(0)
```

Of course you need to chmod both files to allow execution:

```bash
chmod 755 search_basic.py
chmod 755 search_csv.py
```

Given your above `file1` and `file2`, both produce the same output with the line `./search_basic.py file1 file2` (or respective `./search_csv.py file1 file2`):

```
25353gb1FAa8 found in ['367536', '163226', '163226', '5007632889', '9', '163226', '2017-11-15 20:37:02.034', '2017-11-28 20:55:24.891', 'STB', '25353gb1FAa8', '25353gb1FAa8']
255411429E02 not found, doing other operation
375g1043DC92 found in ['274451', '24575', '24575', '3872531727', '23', '24575', '2017-11-08 11:43:21.15', '2017-11-25 16:30:21.061', 'STB', '375g1043DC92', '375g1043DC92']
07k9975cad1e not found, doing other operation
```

Answer (score 1):

For those finding this question and preferring a bash solution. The following script provides the same functionality in fewer lines.

While there is likely a more computationally efficient method. This was my quick method to grab the output of `grep "$i" "$DRC"` without bothering to run any commands twice. If the output of `grep "$i" "$DRC"` is not wanted. `if grep -q "$i" "$DRC"` will serve as the test.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
SRC=/path/to/file1.csv
DRC=/path/to/file2.csv

for i in $(cut -d "|" -f 7 "$SRC")
    do
    LINE="$(grep "$i" "$DRC")"
    if [ $? == 0 ]
        then
            echo "$i Found in $LINE"
        else
            echo "$i NOT Found"
        fi
    done
```

Comment: Does `$? == 0` mean the string is detected ? So can i swap the echo lines (line 10 and 12) if i use `$? != 0` ?

Comment: @Rooney `$?` expands to the exit status of the last command. In Bash, an exit status of `0` indicates success. But we don't need the `[` or `test` command to check the exit status, because that is what `if` does, so `if grep -q $i $DRC ; then ... ` would do the job

Comment: I prefer doing `if line="$(grep "$i" "$drc")"; then`. I also always use lowercase vars in a script, to avoid any chance of overwriting env vars.